# How to easily resize images via command-line?

Tags: command-line, resize, image-processing

I would like to know how to resize images in Ubuntu. What is the easiest tool to do so?

Comment: Related: [How can I scale all images in a folder to the same width?](http://askubuntu.com/q/135477/78223)

Comment: http://sourcedigit.com/20632-install-converseen-on-ubuntu-16-04-batch-image-resizer-converter-for-linux/

Comment: Related: [Image resizing tool for Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/q/87798/87805).

Answer (score 213, accepted):

nautilus-image-converter is a nautilus extension to mass resize or rotate images. To install nautilus-image-converter in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-image-converter
```

It adds two context menu items in nautlius so you can right-click and choose "Resize Image".
(The other is "Rotate Image").

You can do a whole directory of images in one go if you like and you don't even have to open up an application to do so.

You need to restart your nautilus to see new context menus, run `nautilus -q` and then click the Home folder icon to reload nautilus with the new plug-in.

Comment: Does it work with multiple selections (ie i select 10 files - right click - select Rotate - and the 10 images are rotated) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if restart isn't required. I just installed it, closed all nautils windows and opened new, and I don't have this option. I need to check again after restart.

Comment: [Does not work in Ubuntu 13.10 :(](http://askubuntu.com/a/375068/175489)

Comment: Works great in Fedora 20, too. sudo yum install nautilus-image-converter

Comment: Installs but does not seem to work in 14.04 either :(

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to log out or reboot after installing it--or just do what I did; run `pkill nautilus` and then click the Home folder icon to reload nautilus with the new plug-in.

Comment: ...or just run `nautilus -q` as someone added to the answer since my last comment. :)

Comment: Worth noting, there also is a (apparently identical) [thing for Cajaj](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/caja-image-converter): 
`sudo apt-get install caja-image-converter`

Comment: Downvoted because this requires interacting with a GUI, even though OP asked for a command-line tool.

Comment: Wrong answer downvote. Does not work in command line.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 21.04 comman line. Great tool, exactly what I needed! Thank you :)

Comment: Better compressed result is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Answer (score 424):

First, install [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) via:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then, open a terminal and run this command:

```
convert -resize 20% source.png dest.jpg
```

It will reduce the size *to* 20%, **not** *by* 20%.
The resulting image will be much smaller, 20% of the former size,
and not 20% smaller than before.

You can also specify the size in pixels:

```
convert -resize 1024X768 source.png dest.jpg
```

You can also use: [`mogrify` command-line tool](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) from the same package.

Comment: the command reduces the size to 50%, not by 50%.

Comment: @MatthiasWeiler those are identical, not sure what you mean

Comment: They are only identical for the special case of 50%. `-resize 10%` makes your image 90% smaller.

Comment: if you get an error "no images defined.." it is probably because you did not define destination image... e.g. in the above example, `dest.jpg` is a must :)

Comment: you talk about *mogrify* too; here the differences: https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/03/16/useful-imagemagick-commands/

Comment: I threw together a small script around ImageMagick "convert" to handle the boring stuff about source and target directories in case one wants to convert many images: https://gist.github.com/dtonhofer/6c44186d65d3b15784b64096e60195a0

Comment: re: batch processing (1) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516440  (2) http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_not

Comment: probably that should be dest.png, to match the format of the source image.

Comment: **mogrify** overwrites the image whereas **convert** creates a new file.

Comment: Better compressed result is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Comment: Looks like it defaults to 80% compression (precision 8) -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024947/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-quality-level-of-a-jpeg In my opinion, if quality really matters, then you want 90%, but 80% should be enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 165):

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

The command `mogrify` overwrites the original files with the resized images:

```
mogrify -resize 50% *.png      # keep image aspect ratio
mogrify -resize 320x240 *.png  # keep image aspect ratio
mogrify -resize 320x240! *.png # don't keep image aspect ratio
mogrify -resize x240 *.png     # don't keep image aspect ratio
mogrify -resize 320x *.png     # don't keep image aspect ratio
```

<sup>Note: You can add `-auto-orient` to automatically orient converted images.</sup>

Comment: Don't keep aspect ration with `convert`: `convert hospital.jpg -resize 2000x! hospital_2000.jpg`

Comment: Perfect and simplest possible answer with both situations. love it !

Comment: the initial images are **replaced** with the new resized ones. in case you need the initial ones, make a backup

Comment: `320x` *does* keep image aspect ratio. It sets the height to the appropriate value, thus the *ratio* is kept. Maybe you confused something here?

Comment: Better compressed result is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Answer (score 23):

If you're just doing a couple of images, most image editors in Ubuntu (Gimp, F-Spot, etc) will let you do a basic resize.

If you want to edit tens, hundreds or thousands of images, I prefer [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/). Phatch is a GUI-based batch photo editor that will let you perform a whole load of transformations on images. `sudo apt-get install phatch`

ImageMagick is good but it's a bit tedious if you don't know the setting names for things. You can very quickly learn Phatch by clicking around.

Comment: F-Spot does resize? Where?

Comment: While installing `phatch` my `Chrome Browser` got closed and I was unable to relaunch it, I had to remove `phatch` and other packages it installed to get chrome back to working state.

Answer (score 17):

ImageMagick is the package you want. It contains a number of useful command line tools for this very purpose.

[Here's](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/16524.html) a simple tutorial explaining how to batch resize images:-

```
mogrify -resize 320x240 *.jpg
```

> After this command is completed, all of the images will be replaced with resized version of themselves. Notice that in an effort to preserve the image aspect ratio, mogrify may not be produce images that are exactly 320x240. To force this to happen, modify the original command to by placing an exclamation point at the end of the desired resolution:

```
mogrify -resize 320x240! *.jpg
```

Comment: Better compressed result is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Answer (score 15):

No need to install any new software just do this

```
convert -resize 50% myfigure.png myfigure.jpg
```

or

```
convert myfigure.png -resize 200x100 myfigure.jpg
```

Comment: No new software - except for imagemagick, the package that contains convert.

Comment: Better compressed result is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Answer (score 11):

At the moment [**nautilus-image-converter** does not work in **Ubuntu 13.10**](https://askubuntu.com/q/374911/175489). Therefore I use **imagemagick** on the command line, which is very good workaround (at least for me).

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Keep in mind the [difference between these imagemagick tools](http://jaibeermalik.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/imagemagick-mogrify-vs-convert-which-one-to-use-and-when/):

- **Mogrify** does processing on the same image, it reads file modify file
  and writes the output to the same file.
- **Convert** is meant to work on
  separate images, reads file and modify and write to different
  file/format. You can also use convert command to use output file same
  as input file.

I often use *mogrify* to simply resize multiple images and overwrite the original files. I. e. this command would scale down the dimension of all JPG files to 40% of the original dimension:

```
mogrify -verbose -resize '40%' *.JPG
```

Comment: Better compressed result is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Answer (score 8):

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is probably the easiest way, since it has a fairly simple UI for such common tasks. All you have to do is open up your image and go to Image → Image Size and then change accordingly. There are ways to do batch resizing using the GIMP as well, but I don't know them by heart.

Answer (score 8):

Install [gthumb](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gthumb). Simple and easy for basic image handling and editing functions - viewer, resizing, cropping, rotate, flip, grayscale, etc with options to save in  JPEG, PNG, TIFF, TGA formats.

To install gthumb:

- Open your terminal
- Type `sudo apt-get install gthumb`
- Accept the changes

Comment: On Linux Mint, it was optimal solution for me.

Comment: I am used to rotate my photos with gthumb.

Comment: Please add the hint to your solution that you can set under gthumb->preferences->Viewer the zoom behaviour after (re)loading an image. Works great with svg files too. Reale saved my life when working with figures generated from matplotlib...

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the ubiquitous `ffmpeg` (or `avconv`) tool to resize images:

```
ffmpeg -i image.jpg -s 4096x2048 image-resized.jpg
```

And if you want really fast JPEG image resizing - try [epeg](https://github.com/mattes/epeg) (as mentioned [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/6748/2895) and [there](http://leocharre.com/articles/faster-image-resizing-in-linux/)) - which needs to be built from source.

Comment: The quality is very good compared to convert and mogrify from ImageMagick. This is my favorite one.

Comment: Better compressed result is with `optipng` [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440003/22308)

Answer (score 4):

For GUI, [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/) "one click is worth thousand photos" is the best for such quick job.
It is already in Ubuntu repository. It has plenty of actions and options as `imagemagick`.

```
sudo apt-get install phatch
```

**Update:**

Phatch project is DISCONTINUED unfortunately, last code commit was on  2011-01-24. It is on LP/Launchpad (Frameworks: Python2/PyGTK2.8)

Comment: Not available to install for Ubuntu 20.04.2; gives "E: Unable to locate package phatch"

Comment: @brewmanz It is was discontinues, and pygtk2.8 was dropped from repository.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good **multiplatform** tool called [XnConvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/). Combine and choose between more than 80 different operations. The installation is simple through deb. file from the official website.

It is free but not opensource, perhaps that's just the beauty of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

open the image in ImageMagick.

1. click on the image command box will be open.
2. view->resize enter the pixel you want. click on resize button.
3. File-> save, enter the name. click on Format button choose the format you want and click select button.
4. click on save button.

another option is
select view -> original image and Drag the corners of the image to resize it. select File -> save.

Answer (score 1):

I use Pimagizer. It works great and it is the easiest application I have used. **Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04, 15.10**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vfrico/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pimagizer
```

See : https://launchpad.net/pimagizer/ for more infos.