# Tool for high picture compression with low loss of quality

Tags: image-processing, compression

Is there a tool which can achieve high picture compression while preserving (as much as possible) the image quality and can compress images in batches, in order to make optimal images for websites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know `pngcrush` and `optipng`.

There is also `pngquant` and `pngnq`  but those are lossy when the original was in truecolor.

For photos you probably want to convert to JPEG instead.

Comment: links removed as they were broken

Comment: I tested optipng and pngquant, and the result is pngquant 3 times faster and save much more disk space compared to optipng.

Answer (score 6):

If you want an easy to use tool, try [Trimage](http://trimage.org/), which can be found in the Software-Center of Ubuntu. I've also tested pngcrush and optipng but I have to say that Trimage had the best compression rate of these three tools, without having to mess around with the console :-)

```
sudo apt-get install trimage
```

Comment: It feels very bad : http://s18.postimg.org/59b541b2h/Screenshot_from_2016_03_06_15_54_36.png

Comment: `imagemagick` is very good tool. http://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look into the new WebP format and the tool provided by Google. Is not very useful right now, but according to Google it has 40% size reduction over jpeg, without additional quality loss.

http://code.google.com/speed/webp/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1585577

Comment: The examples that Google gives only prove that WebP can make files smaller when the quality is worse (duh!).  There is currently no proof that it can make smaller files at the same quality when compared to JPEG (actually, most tests say it's worse than JPEG).  JPEG2000 **can** make smaller files at the same quality, but it shares one problem with WebP: most browsers don't support it out of the box, so it's useless for use on websites...

Answer (score 0):

I used gimp and followed these instructions:
http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-jpeg.html

When using Trimage I only got a 2.5% improvement on a 2Mb file but with gimp and exporting as jpeg and dialing the quality down to 10 I got a 2Mb file down to 200Kb  or ~90% improvement.