# How can I resize 300 images at the same time?

Tags: resize, imagemagick, image-processing, batch

I have a folder whose contents include ~300 images. I want to resize them to 800px wide in another folder. How can I do that? I have tried some ImageMagick command.

Comment: See this: [How can I scale all images in a folder to the same width?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135477/how-can-i-scale-all-images-in-a-folder-to-the-same-width)... Moreover, [edit] the question to include what imagemagick commands you have already tried and what were the results..

Answer (score 1):

For GUI, [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/) "one click is worth thousand photos" is the best for such quick job.
It is already in Ubuntu repository.

```
sudo apt-get install phatch
```

Otherwise for advanced users, as an example to loop through files in shell:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Configuration
ext="bmp"
count=0
total=0

#loop through all files in the current folder that ends with $ext extension
for i in $(ls *.$ext)
    do
        total=$(($total + 1))

            #replace the 'potrace -s "$i"' with your converting cmd
            #"$i" is the file name
            #it will count +1 if successful
        potrace -s "$i" && count=$(($count + 1))
    done

echo "$count/$total files converted"
#wait
read
```

This example converts `bmp` to `svg`, I wrote it previously for my brother to convert his scanned comic/anime drawings into vectorial form. Before coloring.