# How can I resize pictures in foot or inch units?

Tags: convert, inkscape, image-processing

I have many pictures. I'm going to resize them all together from command line in feet, or if it's not possible in inches.

I know there are GUI apps that can do this but it works only one by one and it takes time to do this work!

I tried the `Convert -resize` command but it's only in pixel format and when I check in Inkscape that size is not what I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: Tried ImageMagick? Check this answer- http://askubuntu.com/a/135489/117406 , for help.

Comment: yes I did...what I mean is convert pictures in foot or inch unit..

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question, but once you set your final measurements isn't it just a [conversion](http://www.ninjaunits.com/convert-pixels-inches/) away to pixels?

Comment: Related: [This post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109826/125388) on Unix & Linux SE asked how to use `imagemagick` to convert images in `mm` (milimeter) unit and the answer pointed to do conversion from `mm` to `pixel` according to DPI requirement. This might be applicable for other units as well.

Answer (score 2):

Image files like jpeg or png store discrete pixels only. How long 10 pixels are is purely a matter of convention or use. If you diplay the pixels on an old 70 dpi monitor, 10 pixels are 1/7 inch. If you print the pixels on a high resolution 1200 dpi printer, the 10 pixels are a mere 1/120 inch long.

So before you can talk about resizing in terms of real world lengths like foot or meter, you need to fix (fake) a resolution.

Then there are still two ways to resize. Just pretend them to have a different resolution. Or have a program like ImageMagick compute a different number of ***pixels*** pretending they keep the resolution. In the end resizing always means to change the number of pixels, whether you do it explicitly or your display or print program does it under the hood to fit the original number of pixels into a given frame size.

Answer (score 1):

I got how to resize!

First check picture info:

```
$ identify -verbose file.jpg
Geometry:
Resolution:
Print Size (inch):
Geomtry=Print Size X Resolution
```

Then do

```
convert -resize XxY! file.jpg output.jpg
```

Comment: my problem is sometimes it doesnot show gemotry or it shows sometimes in centimeter...;(

Comment: You should update your question, not add as an answer. Anyhow, there is a field, `Units` right below print, you can write  a shell script to alter the calculations appropriately