# What advanced image editor should I choose in Ubuntu for web developer work?

Tags: 18.04, image-editor

EDITO:
I'm creating a website and the images they gave me are too big.
In Windows I used Photoshop to reduce the size, or maybe it is better to say scale the size, because I want to keep the whole image, in a smaller size, to be able to put them in the grid.

I ask for advice here, because I never use an editor in Ubuntu, I see all that there is in: Ubuntu Software, but not what would be the most appropriate for professional image editing,
in the creation of a website, and to be able to give the best possible appearance to the images.
In this case, reduce the size of some images, or perhaps it would be better to say, re-dimension.
Thank you.

Comment: This is getting flagged for closing because you ask a very generic thing (best of) for a specific task. You  should edit the question and the title in order to ask exactly what you want, namely **how to reduce the size of images**. And then this would most probably be flagged as duplicate ([How to easily resize images via command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1164/47206)) unless you formulate your question like "How to resize images in Ubuntu with a GUI program?".

Comment: For simple resizing, the most efficient tool is probably ImageMagick, which also offers a command-line tool to easily batch-convert lots of files. But like cipricus already said, as it stands, your question is too opinion-based for this site's format.

Comment: Even then it would be a duplicate of [How can I compress images?](https://askubuntu.com/q/781497/47206), where the answer is Trimage (`sudo apt-get install trimage`). There  is of course Gimp, already posted in an answer hereunder.

Comment: I used www.Photopea.com on Ubuntu. You can even minify PNGs.

Comment: Trimage, mentioned in my comment above has the option to resize multiple images at the same time but I  don't see a setting for the level of resizing. CLI is the best option I guess.

Comment: Thank you all for your support. Edit the question as you suggested, hoping to have done this, in the best possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GUI Workaround:

Gimp (GNU Image manipulating program) is equivalent to Photoshop in Gnu/Linux distributions.

Open your image in Gimp then from "File" menu select "Export as", choose "JPEG" as export format and click on <kbd>Export</kbd>

It will results this window:

[image]

Adjust your desired values and save the result.

You'll get similar settings for other formats if any is available, for example png:

[image]

In this way you can work around your images similar to Photoshop.

#### CLI

You can also achieve this goal using command line using "imagemagick" package.

```
convert -quality 50% input.png output.png
```

Comment: Thank you @Ravexina, accept the duplicate without seeing your answer. I hope you gave me your choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's all based on your needs and preference, but a common image viewer with basic editing tools is "gwenview" and for Adobe Photoshop replacement you can use "GIMP".

In Gwenview, Edit>Resize

[image: gwenview screenshot]

Also take a look at this topic to see how to batch resize images using imagemagick: [How can I scale all images in a folder to the same width?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135477/how-can-i-scale-all-images-in-a-folder-to-the-same-width)