# how to reduce size of an image from 31.1 kb to between 15kb - 20 kb

Tags: jpeg

As per a requirement mentioned [here](http://ibpsreg.sifyitest.com/cwespljan13/photoupload_static.php)
the size of photos submitted should be between 20kb-50kb.

I have my scanned photos which have been cropped but the sizes are still ~139 kb.

If I reduce the pixels then the size of image goes less than 20kb in case one and less than 10 kb in case two.

I have to reduce the pixel size but the weight in bytes is also going down at the same time which is not allowed on my link.These are scanned photos in JPEG format.

The program I'm using is GIMP. If this is possible in GIMP then how do I do so?
If I can't do what I need in GIMP, is there any other program for the same?

Comment: Can you read the community wiki [this topic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Photos/ResizingPhotos) and tell us whether it helped you?

Comment: I have read the community wiki and it did not helped me, the situation is if I reduce the pixel size the image size becomes less than 10 kb I can not reduce the size of image less than 10 kb otherwise the scanned photo can not be submitted to the link I gave on the same time pixel size also has to be kept in permissible range

Comment: If I understand the question right, the OP's problem is that if they resize the image to the prescribed size (140x60 pixels), then any JPEG compression settings in GIMP produce a file which is **smaller** than the lower allowed limit (10Kb). GIMP is too efficient at compressing images :) I tried this and can confirm that I've got images smaller than 10Kb at minimum compression. The question is how to *increase* the file size to be within 10-20Kb while keeping image dimensions the same

Comment: @Sergey, please look at the editing history of this question. I had tried to clean it up but may have done too much.

Comment: @vasa1: I think the last edit by the OP describes exactly what I'm describing, or am I reading it wrong? Their images are now too small.

Answer (score 9):

Use Gimp's 'Save for Web' plugin. You can [download and install it manually](http://registry.gimp.org/node/33), or just add the `gimp-plugin-registry` package from the Software Center which includes it (and many more).

Once installed, you just open the image in Gimp, select File -> Save for Web then play with the output settings until you have what you want. There are two tabs on the left. One is for image quality, one is for image size. You can even output the image in a different image format. As you make changes, the output file size (shown below the picture) updates. I use this plugin constantly and highly recommend it.

[image: save for web quality tab]

[image: save for web size tab]

For me, the only problem is that with very large images it sometimes won't launch. If I resize down from say 100MB to a 10MB image size, it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

There are several solution in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images) using both GUI and command line utilities.

For example:

[aneeshep](https://askubuntu.com/users/4980/aneeshep) suggested to use

> ```
> convert  -resize 50% source.png dest.jpg and 
>
> convert  -resize 1024X768  source.png dest.jpg
> ```

Or even use the GIMP's built-it abilities suggested by [tommy-brunn](https://askubuntu.com/users/334/tommy-brunn):

> GIMP is probably the easiest way, since it has a fairly simple UI for such common tasks. All you have to do is open up your image and go to Image → Image Size and then change accordingly. There are ways to do batch resizing using the GIMP as well, but I don't know them by heart.

Comment: Hi! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: see the image I am having is now in permissible range 20 kb but the pixel size is 300x70 or above if I reduce the pixel size the 20 kb goes becomes 15 kb I do not have to reduce the byte size and at the same time reduce the pixel size (this is a constraint by the link I gave) is there a way in this situation?

Comment: Thanks for the tip :-) Hope that the new version is better..

Comment: Registered User, Which format are you using?

Comment: I am  using JPEG and it is Ubuntu 12.04 and gimp is 2.6.12

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following packages for Nautilus:

```
nautilus-image-converter - nautilus extension to mass resize or rotate images
nautilus-image-manipulator - Resize and send images from Nautilus
```

You can install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-image-*
```

After that restart Nautilus even by killing it (`killall -9 nautilus`) or by rebooting/logging out and back in.

You will have a context menu by right-clicking the images. You can rotate and resize the images in the simplest way.

Comment: Thanks your tool is helping me I have one doubt the size of image I have been able to bring in permissible range 20-50 kb but the pixels of image are also limited to be not more than 200x230 kb if I reduce the pixels then the size becomes less than 20 kb is there a solution in this situation?

Comment: The size in kb-s depends on: 1. size of the image in pixels, 2. the compression used, 3. the complexity of colors in the image. To reach your target, decrease the size with 40-50%!

Answer (score 1):

To decrease image sizes in GIMP we have several approaches. Use a combination of all for best results:

- [Crop image](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-crop.html)
  Usually there are parts of an image we do not want to keep in the final published version. Start with cropping your image to the desired content. Crop to selection is quite easy to perform as it allows you to select the interesting area prior to crop. This also includes a fixed geometry we may want to have.
- [Scale Image](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-scale.html)
  Scanned images or photos of a modern digital camera are usually way to large to fit on a standard screen. We may want to scale the image down to the desired final size.
- [Despeckle](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-despeckle.html)
  This plugin (accessed with *Filters --> Enhance --> Despeckle*) does not only allow to remove speckles or artifacts from scanned images. It also helps to smooth the image which may lead to a dramatic improvement in efficiancy of a later compression.
- [Export](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-file-export.html)
  In the "Export" dialog we can export an image to [any compressed format](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-images-out.html#gimp-using-fileformats) by file extension. For JPEG compression choose `filename.jpg`. There we can also adjust the resulting image quality, with less quality on smaller sizes. For JPEG the optimum quality would be at about 90% but we can compress down to less than 70% without over obvious artifacts. This also depends on the image content. Use the preview option to control artifacts and choose a lower quality unitl the resulting image size is small enough but still has not too many artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have GIMP installed and running, you *do not need to* install any additional software.

The easiest solution would be to adjust the compression settings when saving as JPEG - moving the slider to 95-100% will somewhat increase file size compared to the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

For image editing and re sizing best software is **GIMP image editor** .Install this using **Software Manager**.

To reduce Image size:
Step 1:Right click on the image and open as GIMP image editor.

Step 2:Now Check the footer of the image and reduce the PX percentage (as per requirement)
[image]

Step 3: Now Click to file and export the image.

Step 4: Finally check the image size.
[image]

This is the easiest way to reduce image size.If you have any more doubt please feel free to ask.Thanks..

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. The percentage at the bottom is the zoom level, it doesn't actually change the size of the image. To do that, use Image, Scale Image.

Comment: Its working for me.I don't know what happen to you.if you want you can send me the image i can fixed this in the same way.my mail id is kousikroy[at]gmail.com

Comment: This answer is wrong, you're actually changing the zoom level (hint: check View - Zoom after changing the value in that dropdown). Any difference in size is probably caused by different compression settings.