# How to resize images in 13.10 using the context menu in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, 13.10, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to resize images with the context menu (or similar easy way) in Ubuntu 13.10.

I read about [nautilus-image-converter](https://askubuntu.com/q/1164/175489) and installed it. But it does not show up, even after a system restart.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **Nautilus Actions** like **nautilus-image-converter** and many others, which I regard as indispensable, are not (yet) even showing up in the context menu under Ubuntu 13.10. This is one of the several reasons why I decided to switch back to 13.04!

You can perhaps help prioritize this issue by reporting that this bug also affects you here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-actions-extra/+bug/1244221

As a temporary solution you may use the commands (or even create your custom **Nautilus Scripts**) mentioned in other answers here: [How to easily resize images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images)

Comment: Ok thnx for the info. I'll take part on this bug report. The command line tool **mogrify** helped me, as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/375068/175489)