# Resize image to specific size

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I know there are several ways to resize an image via the command line. Some of them are specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images-via-command-line). However, I was wondering whether there is a way to specify the size of the resized image, e.g. I want to resize an image that is 8.5 MB big to an image that is 2.5 MB. Preferably, the solution uses imagemagick.

Comment: Do you want to achieve the reduction solely through image data compression, or are you ready to change image resolution (pixel count) too?

Comment: I prefer data compression. The goal is to achieve the best image quality, but reduce the size so that I can upload the image to an online-forum

Comment: Resize the image to the resolution of a screen (i.e., HD is 1920x1080) and you will already have an image far less than 8 MB *and* in max quality for screen display.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Though it does not solve my problem. The ratios of the images may differ (2:3, 3:4, 16:19 etc.) and I want to make sure that every image ends up being 2.5 MB which is the maximal size for upload in the forum and thus ensures the best quality

Comment: Yes it does. And no, 2,5 MB is not necessarily ensuring the best quality. For on screen display, it probably will be overkill. Start with reducing the size to the display resolution. That will usually bring you already below 2 MB. If that doesn't, increase the jpeg compression until it does. The result will be very acceptable. If it is only a few images, Gimp allows to see the resulting file size while you tweak the compression settings.

Comment: I found an obscure setting allowing to set the maximum size: see my answer. Still, for your application, prefer to adjust the image to the screen display resolution first. You can go much lower than 2 Mb for optimum on screen display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With credit to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917219/imagemagick-scale-jpeg-image-with-a-maximum-file-size), there is a jpeg codec option for Imagemagick's `convert` supports an option  for jpeg that allows to restrict the size of the output file: `-define jpeg:extent=max_value`. It is used as:

```
convert test.jpg -define jpeg:extent=1M testout.jpg
```

If anyone could tell where such settings are officially documented, I will include it in this answer.