# How to resize an image using ImageMagick

Tags: command-line, image-processing, imagemagick

From [How to easily resize images via command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images-via-command-line) I know I can use this command to resize an image in bash:

```
convert -resize 1024X768  source.png dest.jpg
```

But I'm stuck at only providing the width and keeping the aspect ratio.

`man convert` does not provide any help for `-resize` flag.

I want something like `convert -resize 1024 -keep-ratio source.png dest.png`

What would be the command?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/25134 - after following your link. Seems `!` signifies `don't keep aspect ratio`

Comment: @Hannu, I **want** to keep the aspect ratio. None of the commands in the answer link you mentioned do that. I need to **keep** aspect ratio, and I need to only provide the width.

Comment: Yes!? So, as I understand the examples;  do NOT include a `!`,

Comment: @Hannu, then what is the command? I'm confused. I have not included `!` in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convert -resize` by default does keep the aspect ratio (unless `!` is specified). So to resize based on width alone you would just need to do: `convert -resize 1024 source.png dest.png`

To convert based on the height alone for example: `convert -resize x768 source.png dest.png`

`-resize` takes the [Geometry](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html) parameter. Take a look at the docs I linked as well as [resize examples](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/).

Comment: that worked great. Now I'm in a situation that I need to resize based only on height. If I provide a single value, it takes it as the width parameter. What syntax should I use?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I updated my answer above.

Comment: thank you so much.